# How to handle soap response in php

Tags: php, web-services, soap, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I need to use soap calls for my application so i googled a bit about some libraries in laravel and found one:

[Laravel SoapClient Wrapper](https://github.com/artisaninweb/laravel-soap)

It's not documented a lot so i'm kinda stuck. I have successfully retrieved data but cannot display it on page because it is "NULL". So if anyone can help me where i did wrong?

My code is next

```
//variable is null at beggining
$rac=null;
SoapWrapper::add(function ($service) {
        $service
            ->name('test')
            ->wsdl('http://wdsl-link');
    });

$data = [
        'param' => '111111'
];

SoapWrapper::service('test', function ($service) use ($data) {
        $rac = $service->call('getSmth', [$data])->structure;
        //Tried with sleep so variable $rac can be assigned but no results
        //sleep(5); 
        //dd here works and i got my desired data
        //dd($rac);
    });
//dd don't work here and variable $rac is null
//dd($rac);
return view('pages/...',compact('rac'));
```

It's not about syntax, it's about my bad understanding of handling soap responses. So if anyone can tell me how to get that response or maybe some advice to use some other library for soap which works with Laravel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current code, there are two variables with the same name `$rac`:

- the first one available to the outside only.
- the second one available to the inside closure only.

That is the reason why your outside `$rac` is null at the end. To make the changes in the closure applied to the existing instance of the first `$rac` variable. Change you code to:

```
SoapWrapper::service('test', function ($service) use ($data, &$rac) {
    // notice the $rac variable is included as reference in the `use`

    $rac = $service->call('getSmth', [$data])->structure;
});
```